# TestSubject in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

I am looking at a java implementation by Netflix of Reactive Extensions called RxJava.

It would appear that they have chosen to implement the .NET `Subject<T>` as `TestSubject<T>`. Does anyone know why its called `TestSubject<T>` which to me would infer that it probably shouldn't be used?

I can't see how else I will create an Observable from a method within a class. E.g.

```
public class MyClass extends MyBase {

    @Override
    public void onText(String text) {
        // TODO: push onto some observable here - do I use a TestSubject?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent class in Java is called `PublishSubject<T>` as `Subject` is the abstract base.